# Repair package catalogue in ubuntu 12.04 due to Pidgin facebook chat Plugin

Tags: 12.04, software-center, pidgin

I tried to install **facebook chat plugins** for **Pidgin**, and the package was broken. So, now I can't install or remove any package. The software center is showing **Repair package catalog** dialogue. I tried to run dpkg --configure -a, the following is the output:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pidgin-facebookchat:
pidgin-data (1:2.10.3-0ubuntu1.3) breaks pidgin-facebookchat (<< 1.69-2) and is installed.
Version of pidgin-facebookchat to be configured is 1.69.
dpkg: error processing pidgin-facebookchat (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
pidgin-facebookchat
```

what should I do to repair the problem? Please help.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem. It helped for me to uninstall the plugin again. So open a terminal window and enter:

```
sudo apt-get remove pidgin-facebookchat
```

I hope this will help.